# Error on for loop when referring to the incrementing variable i

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, vuex

I am trying to check if an object exists in an array. Basically what I wanted to do was if an object exist then remove it from the array, or else push the object in to the array. But I am always getting an error.

type of object returned from the api:

```
{
    "id": 23,
    "status": "Available",
    "column_id": 5,
    "row_id": 1
},
{
    "id": 24,
    "status": "Available",
    "column_id": 6,
    "row_id": 1
},
```

I am using Vue.js and whenever an object is clicked,  inside the Vuex store action I am checking if that object exist in an array. But I am always getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

store.js:

```
state: {
    selectedSeats: [],
},

actions: {
    getSelectedSeats(context, payload) {
        let found = false;
        if (context.state.selectedSeats.length < 1) {
            console.log('empty');
            context.commit('mutateSelectedSeat', payload);
        }
        else {
            console.log('not empty');
            for (let i = 0; i <= context.state.selectedSeats.length; i++) {
                if (payload.id === context.state.selectedSeats[i].id) {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            console.log('after loop');
            if (found) {
                console.log('found');
            }
            else {
                console.log('not found');
            }
        }

    }
}
```

However, doing this way doesn't give any errors:

```
...
    if (payload.id === context.state.selectedSeats[0].id) {
        found = true;
...
```

I think the problem is with the variable `i`. But I have no idea what am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(context.state.selectedSeats[i], i)` above `if (payload.id === context.state.selectedSeats[i].id)`

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Ok,.. I am getting this `undefined 1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `i < context.state.selectedSeats.length` instead of `i <= context.state.selectedSeats.length`. Classic off-by-one error.

Comment: So indeed it is `undefined` on which you are trying to access `id`? How are you removing items?

Comment: @Xufox Yes! OMG.. I have been debugging this small bug from the morning! Thank you.

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal Didn't get to that part yet... as I first wanted to check the object in the array. :(